# Why is Volley Library usually combined with okHttp Library?

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

Why is Volley usually combined with okHttp? Why is it done like this?

eg:

```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
   client.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());
   mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new OkHttpStack(client));
```

Answer (score 9):

**Volley needs an HttpStack** when you create the [RequestQueue](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.java).

If you don't provide one, Volley will create an stack depending on your API level: If you are running API 9 or below it'll be based on the AndroidHttpClient. If you are running API 10 or above it'll be based on HttpURLConnection.

[OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) is an modern, fast and efficient Http client which supports HTTP/2 and SPDY and does a lot of stuff for you like connection pooling, gziping, caching… and so on. OkHttp acts like the transport layer.

OkHttp uses [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio), a library that complements java.io and java.nio to make it much easier to access, store, and process your data.

For those reasons I recommend you to use and OkHttp Stack. I'm using [this one](https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750) that does not use okhttp-urlconnection.

I've written an [article about using OkHttp, Volley and Gson](https://medium.com/@sotti/android-networking-i-okhttp-volley-and-gson-72004efff196) for Android networking that you might find interesting.

Comment: do we need HttpStack even after OkHttp getting used from Android 4.4 internally?

Comment: @rcde0 KitKat was released a few years ago and probably has a very old version of OkHttp, this is not an answer to your question but just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @ Sotti, 
I read your nice article but, by android studio can Not find class - "OkHttpStack"
even after adding -

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

Comment: @CRSardar in my answer (just right above, you have the link to the OkHttpStack as you need to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) on why okhttp is nice for transport - then you will know why it is often combined with volley

Comment: It's Because volley cannot handle HTTP requests?

Comment: Separation of Concern is the key here

Comment: this doesn't really explain why we need Volley at all